# Why is my unique constraint getting confused with a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a schema with tables like this (simplified):

```
--------        ---------------        ------------
| key  |        | permission  |        | resource |
|------|        |-------------|        |----------|
| id   | -----< | id          | >----- | id       |
| name |        | key_id      |        | name     |
--------        | resource_id |        ------------
                | action      |
                ---------------
```

The `permission` table definition script is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `permission` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY_KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_permission_key` FOREIGN KEY (`key_id`) REFERENCES `key` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_permission_resource` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_id`) REFERENCES `resource` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

This all works fine. Then, I decided I needed a unique constraint on the `permission` table so that only a single record can exist for an action/key/resource combination, so I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE `permission` ADD UNIQUE KEY `uq_permission` (`key_id`, `resource_id`, `action`);
```

This also works fine. We are in an environment where we use migrations to manage schema changes, so I want to make sure that there's a "roll back" script. But when I issue this command:

```
ALTER TABLE `permission` DROP INDEX `uq_permission`;
```

I get this error:

> 1553 - Cannot drop index 'uq_permission': needed in a foreign key
> constraint

After some fuddling around, I found that if I dropped the foreign key `fk_permission_key`, I am then able to drop the unique constraint.

Why is my unique constraint getting tangled up with a completely separate foreign key?

Comment: Create another index suitable for FK (by separate column for example) then delete your index.

Comment: This could be a bug. I recently reported a behavior that ended up being a bug. I would suggest, try this in sql server and see if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the `fk_permission_key` constraint, MySQL automatically creates an index (this behaviour differs from other database engines, where you need to create such indexes explicitly):

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM `permission`;
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| permission |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_key      |            1 | key_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_resource |            1 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When you create the `uq_permission` index, MySQL apparently drops the `fk_permission_key` index because it understands it can use your own index.

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM `permission`;
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| permission |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            1 | key_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            2 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            3 | action      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_resource |            1 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

However, if you now attempt to remove `uq_permission` MySQL complaints because the foreign key will no longer have a usable index (and this time it isn't smart enough to create the index automatically).

I don't know if automatic index creation is configurable but, in this case, the only solution I can think of is to provide the index yourself:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `permission` ADD INDEX `fk_permission_key` (`key_id`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM `permission`;
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| permission |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            1 | key_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            2 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          0 | uq_permission          |            3 | action      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_resource |            1 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_key      |            1 | key_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE `permission` DROP INDEX `uq_permission`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM `permission`;
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| permission |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_resource |            1 | resource_id | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| permission |          1 | fk_permission_key      |            1 | key_id      | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Automatic index creation is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
> foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. **Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
> another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key
> constraint.** index_name, if given, is used as described previously.